# Error in omitting semicolon - can someone explain why?

Tags: javascript, compiler-errors, automatic-semicolon-insertion

Can someone please explain why if I omit the semicolon in the line `while(nums[right-1] == nums[right--]);`that I get a syntax error? I generally understand the point of semicolons, but why this specific line and not the others?

```
var threeSum = function(nums) {
    nums.sort((a,b)=>a-b);
    let result = [];
    for (let i=0;i<nums.length;i++) {
        let t = -nums[i];
        let left = i+1, right = nums.length-1;
        while(left < right) {
            if (nums[left] + nums[right] == t) {
                result.push([nums[i], nums[left], nums[right]]);
                while(nums[left+1] == nums[left++]);
                while(nums[right-1] == nums[right--]);
            } else if (nums[left]+nums[right] < t) left++;
            else right--;
        }
        while(nums[i+1]==nums[i]) i++
    }

    return result;

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A loop needs something to loop over.  Basically either a statement or a code block.  For example:

```
while (something) {
  this.isInACodeBlock();
}
```

or:

```
while (something)
  this.isAStatement();
```

Keep in mind that a *statement* can be a no-op.  A semicolon by itself serves that purpose.  And since carriage returns don't matter to the language, this is a loop with a statement:

```
while (something);
```

Taking a step out, this loop is *within* a code block, which ends right after the loop:

```
if (somethingElse) {
  while (something)
}
```

If there was just a statement following the `while` loop then it would be syntactically correct, even if the behavior is unexpected or a bug.  But there's a closing curly brace.

So the interpreter is expecting either a statement or an opening block, but it's encountering a closing block.  Which is an error.

Comment: Thanks for the summary and clear explanation!  This now makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Good explanation from @David, I will add that to avoid theses kind of error you should consider to follow a styling guide like airbnb. Make your code easier to read.

Way to achieve that: Replace `++` by `+=`. Comment the main parts of your code ... etc

A good code is a code you can understand by reading it. I should have been understand what `threeSums` function is doing and why you are performing theses `while` just by looking at it.

```
// the function do blabla
function threeSums(nums) {
  nums.sort((a, b) => a - b);

  const result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i += 1) {
    // what is t?
    const t = -nums[i];

    let left = i + 1;
    let right = nums.length - 1;

    while (left < right) {
      // what is the case covered by this if?
      if (nums[left] + nums[right] == t) {
        result.push([
           nums[i],
           nums[left],
           nums[right],
        ]);

        while (nums[left + 1] == nums[left]) {
          left += 1;
        }

        while (nums[right - 1] == nums[right]) {
          right -= 1
        }
      } else if (nums[left] + nums[right] < t) {
        left += 1;
      } else {
        right -= 1;
      }
    }

    while (nums[i + 1] == nums[i]) {
      i += 1;
    }
  }

  return result;
};
```

Comment: This function is to take 3 numbers in an array that add up to a target (t) and put them in a separate array.

For instance:
[-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4] should return [-1, 0, 1] and [-1, -1, 2]

Although I follow the logic of your code above, when I run this code, the code hangs, presumably in some sort of infinite loop?

Comment: The snippet is indeed not working. I only use it to show you the code result, sorry If it did confuse you. I should have use the `code` syntax

Comment: @RobinShrestha The code I have showed to you on my answer is exactly the same as yours. Only the syntax changes. All that you said to exaplin the funciton should be on a comment on top of your function in your code

Comment: Right on, the function as written initially had worked, which why I think it's puzzling when running your code (which syntactically makes complete sense on my side), that it hangs.  Perhaps that's another question in itself.  Thanks for taking a look

Comment: Completely agree with the premise here.  Even if the code is a few keystrokes longer, the intent is more clear and bugs are easier to spot.  Issues like this one become a moot point.  I'll take clarity over brevity any day.